# ¿Cómo funciona la precisión en tipo de dato Float en Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

````
-- Se tiene definida la siguiente tabla
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLA
(
   ID        NUMBER (3),
   NUM_TAB   FLOAT (3)
);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLA
     VALUES (24, 24);

SELECT ID, NUM_TAB FROM MY_TABLA;
-- 24   20
```
````

- ¿Por qué en `NUM_TAB` se insertó `20`, si se envió `24`?
- ¿En qué situaciones es recomendable cambiar la precisión que trae un campo `FLOAT` por defecto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿Cómo funciona la precisión en tipo de dato Float en Oracle?

Aunque no es muy claro, la explicación se halla en la documentación aquí: [FLOAT Data Type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref129).

Cuando defines una columna con `FLOAT(n)`, como has podido darte cuenta, `n` no expresa la precisión en cantidad de dígitos decimales, como sucede con el tipo `NUMBER(n)` por ejemplo. Mas bien, `n` representa la precisión en cantidad de *bits*. Y aun eso no es totalmente cierto, la explicación más completa es mucho más complicada. Puedes encontrar más detalles en [esta respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17416421/4955425) si quieres profundizar el tema más allá de mi explicación simplista.

Una forma aproximada de entender el valor `n` es que por cada 3 bits (más o menos) que le definas al tipo `FLOAT`, esto te concede un dígito más a la precisión permitida. Una fórmula sencilla pero que es solo una aproximación es:

```
precisión en dígitos = (n / 3) + 1
```

> ¿Por qué en `NUM_TAB` se insertó `20`, si se envió `24`?

Es porque al especificar una precisión de `3` bits (`FLOAT(3)`), esto en realidad equivale a un solo dígito de precisión (`1 = (3 / 3) + 1`). Para poder expresar `24`, necesitas por lo menos 2 dígitos de precisión, o sea que tendrías que declarar el tipo `FLOAT(n)` con un valor `n` de por lo menos `4`.

Ahora, para entender porqué se sustituyó el valor `24` con `20`, primero hay que entender que cuando hablamos de *dígitos de precisión*, en realidad cuando se trata del tipo `FLOAT` estamos refiriéndonos a *dígitos significativos*. En otras palabras, cuando decimos que `FLOAT(3)` equivale a una precisión de un solo dígito, esto no quiere decir que solo se puedan expresar los números de -9 a 9. Mas bien significa que, sea cual sea el valor expresado, solo puede incluir un máximo de 1 dígito significativo.

Por ejemplo, todos los números siguientes pueden ser expresados con un `FLOAT(3)` sin problemas, porque solo tienen 1 dígito significativo:

- `2       (2e0)`
- `30      (3e1)`
- `400     (4e2)`
- `5000    (5e3)`
- `60000   (6e4)`

En contraste, los números siguientes, aunque mas pequeños en algunos casos, requieren más dígitos significativos:

- `24      (24e0)`  (2 dígitos significativos: `24`)
- `480     (48e1)`  (2 dígitos significativos: `48`)
- `5001    (5001e0)`  (4 dígitos significativos: `5001`)
- `60300   (603e2)`  (3 dígitos significativos: `603`)

En todos estos casos, lo que el tipo `FLOAT` hace es sustituir la entrada con el número aproximado más cercano que se pueda expresar dentro de la cantidad de dígitos significativos permitidos. Por ejemplo, tomando nuevamente los ejemplos arriba, estos son sustituídos de esta manera:

- `24    --> 20    (2e1)`
- `480   --> 500   (5e2)`
- `5001  --> 5000  (5e3)`
- `60300 --> 60000 (6e4)`

> ¿En qué situaciones es recomendable cambiar la precisión que trae un campo `FLOAT` por defecto?

En teoría lo usarías cuando quieres controlar la máxima cantidad de bytes que puede consumir la columna, y si estás dispuesto a sacrificar la precisión de los valores para lograrlo.

Pero Oracle mismo recomienda que, si tienes ese objetivo, es mejor emplear los tipos `BINARY_FLOAT` o `BINARY_DOUBLE` que ya tienen claramente definidos sus límites en bytes, mas bien que complicarse la vida con `FLOAT(n)` donde el significado y efecto del valor `n` es muy confuso.

Y, por supuesto, si no es tu intención permitirle a Oracle que sustituya de forma silenciosa los valores cuando la precisión excede un cierto límite, entonces es mejor emplear el tipo `NUMBER(n)` que es más estricto en su uso, y que lanza un error cuando un valor excede el límite definido, en vez de sustituirlo con una aproximación.